# How do I ignore the space on edittext

Tags: android

I want to get text as input in edittext, but sometimes, they have space at the end of input

Here's an example if user want to search SIDARTO or SIMEON

```
INPUT  | +space  | ORIGIN SEARCH
SI     | SI____  | SIDARTO or SIMEON
```

How do I ignore the space? It can be on code or xml

Comment: used `trim()` to your text like: `String str=edit_text.getText().trim()` it'll remove the space at the end

Comment: Use trim().. isn't it?

Comment: String k = edittext.getText().toString().replace(' ', '');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String s1=edit_text.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 3):

Used `.trim()` to your `String` like:

```
String s1=edit_text.getText().toString().trim();
```

It returns a copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.

**Intput:**

```
String Str = new String("   Welcome to SO   ");
System.out.println(Str.trim() );
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome to SO
```

Comment: It will give error :: The method trim() is undefined for the type CharSequence.

Comment: @ManishDubey you have to add `.toString()` to your `String` for that. i edited check it.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code :

```
String text = edit_text.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

use trim method

```
   String s1=edit_text.getText();
   String s2=s1.trim();
```

Comment: It will raise error :: Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String